# Equivalent for NotFoundObjectResult in .NET 7 isolated worker model Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, http-status-code-400, asp.net-core-7.0

I had this code in **Azure Function** where I have used **.NET 6.0**:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError($"Data Access Failed: {ex.Message}");

    return new NotFoundObjectResult(ex.Message);
}
```

I upgraded the **Azure Function** to **.NET 7.0 Isolated Worker Model**. What is the equivalent in **.NET 7.0 isolated worker model** to return the **HTTP status code** of no data found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below code(`HttpStatusCode.NotFound`) which gives 404 status code:

**`Code:`**

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp77
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik your function is being processed");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("No data found Rithwik!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

In `response.WriteString` written my own message, there you can send exception message